# fiftyone launch_app suddenly not working in jupyterlab / jupyter notebook / vsc

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab, fiftyone

I have an old script of mine that stopped working suddenly
everything work fine until the visualize step:

```
session = fo.launch_app(dataset)
```

seems the cell running and open a space for the app but it doesn't appear in notebook

i've tried to run it in different env ( jupyterlab / jupyter notebook / vsc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it, i had an error i've missed:

> jupyter notebook Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

seems that something changed my windows Registry `.js`
to fix it: `win+r` type: `regedit` and change `Content Type` from `text/plain` to `application/javascript` in:

> Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js
> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.js